# I can't get all link in list product

Tags: php, jquery

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->productlist as $pro) {
  ?>
  <div class="link"><a href="index.php?option=com_ecommerce&view=detail&id=$pro->id" class="basic"></a></div>
  <?php
  $i++; 
}
?>
```

**JS Code**

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
  var link = $('.link .basic').attr('href');
  alert(link);
});
</script>
```

Current ouput:

`index.php?option=com_ecommerce&view=detail&id=1`

The output i would like to have:

```
index.php?option=com_ecommerce&view=detail&id=1
index.php?option=com_ecommerce&view=detail&id=2
index.php?option=com_ecommerce&view=detail&id=3 
index.php?option=com_ecommerce&view=detail&id=n
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: your question is unclear. Please edit it to tell us what you intend to do and comment the code you already built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.link .basic').each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```